# Does my wuzu breaks in this condition

Tags: salat

I want to ask that sometimes when i urinate before performing wuzu for salah then while praying salah i feel that a little amount of water is on the tip of my penis its not sticky like sperms its just like water. In that condition does my wuzu breaks or i shall start my praying after wiping that because it is like water not sperms and in very low amount should i perform wuzu again or not if this happen.